# Put harddisk with debian installation on it into another laptop of the same type

Tags: boot

I have a Debian 11 installation on a Thinkpad T460 (Type 20FM-S5DX00). But this laptop does not start anymore.

I took the hard drive out of there and put it into a Thinkpad X250. Pressing F12 when booting up, there were two entries in the boot device selection. First was just 'debian' and the second was the hard disk. But I could not boot Debian.

Would it work on another device of exactly the same type, i.e. on a second T460 (Type 20FM-S5DX00)?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to get to the files on the harddisk? Do you want to "rescue" and continue using that Debian installation? Both? Does the T460 laptop have 1 drive or more?

Comment: @Gantendo Thank you for your comment! Appreciate it a lot! The primary goal is to get the files on the harddisk. Just some txt files. The secondary goal would be, to get the virtual machines I have there. To get the VMs I would have to 'rescue' the installation, I guess, so that I can export them. The T460 has one physical drive and there ist just one Debian 11 installation on it.

Comment: If not encrypted then you can access everything from a live session, no need to transplant drives (like it would help with anything).

Comment: @ChanganAuto The harddrive is not encrypted. But the laptop with the harddrive does not turn on anymore. Can you elaborate on the live session?

Comment: I was under the impression the OS wasn't booting, not the laptop itself but OK, same method applies but in a different machine with the original drive connected, internally or externally doesn't matter. A live session is what you boot to install a Linux distro (most distros anyway). You can use any to access the files or even the already installed (Linux based) OS in the other machine if you connect the old HDD via USB enclosure/adapter.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you! I get the idea.